# HAProxy config file error using req.cook

Tags: configuration, haproxy, access-control-list

I'm following [this tutorial](http://codeen.co.uk/ab-testing-with-haproxy-and-nginx/) (more or less) in an attempt to use haproxy for a quick-and-easy A/B testing setup, and haproxy doesn't like my config file for some reason that I just can't identify.

Config file:

```
global  
log    127.0.0.1 local1 debug
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
user   haproxy
group  haproxy
daemon

defaults  
log     global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http
bind *:80

acl is_current-area_cookie req.cook(Current-Area) -m found
acl is_new-area_cookie     req.cook(New-Area) -m found
## Other ACL's

use_backend current_area   if is_current-area_cookie
use_backend new_area       if is_new-area_cookie

use_backend weighted_area  if !is_current-area_cookie !is_new-area_cookie
## Other Backend handling

backend current_area
    server current_area 127.0.0.1:81

backend new_area
    server new_area     127.0.0.1:82

backend weighted_area
    server current_area 127.0.0.1:81 weight 70
    server new_area     127.0.0.1:82 weight 30
```

And the errors:

```
[ALERT] 063/165427 (31203) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:27] : error detected while parsing ACL 'is_current-area_cookie'.
[ALERT] 063/165427 (31203) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:28] : error detected while parsing ACL 'is_new-area_cookie'.
[ALERT] 063/165427 (31203) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:31] : error detected while parsing switching rule.
[ALERT] 063/165427 (31203) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:32] : error detected while parsing switching rule.
[ALERT] 063/165427 (31203) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:34] : error detected while parsing switching rule.
[ALERT] 063/165427 (31203) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 063/165427 (31203) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

I've been through all of HAProxy's documentation, especially the stuff about `req.cook()` and can't find anything wrong with my syntax...

Comment: I don't see it, either.  What version or HAProxy?  Oh... did you copy/paste from the blog?  Delete all of those lines from your config and type them in manually, or check your config with a hex editor.  I bet you have the equivalent of an `&nbsp;` or `&ndash;` pasted in there somewhere, inadvertently putting some utf-8 or a latin1 character with the high bit set, where only ascii is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Ubuntu's repos contain a rather old (1.4) version of HAProxy and this example uses some directives that were added in 1.5.

After upgrading to the latest stable release (1.6) this config works.